# Reading elements from a string in C

Tags: c, while-loop, char, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to print the first letter of a word at the position entered by the user. If there is a whitespace, then it will just stop searching. **There is a warming message concerning funtion `gets()`**. I have problems with the pointers and funtion, **it just does not return the letter**. I think the porblem might be on the `while` loop. Function `firstLetter` prints the first letter of a word. For instance, if the user enters index 5 of a previously entered string, and in str[5] corresponds to the 'e' of the word 'ice-cream' then the `firstLetter` will search for the first letter of that word, in this case it will return 'i'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int firstLetter(int , char *);

int main()
{
    char str[200];
    printf("Insert line: ");
    gets(str);
    
    int pstn;
    scanf("%i,&pstn");
    
    firstLetter(pstn, str);
    
    
    return 0;
}

int firstLetter(int i, char *str)
{
    if(str[i]=' ')
    {
        printf("No letters at this position");
    }
    
    else
    {
        while(str[i]!=' ')
        {
            i--;
        }
        printf("First letter: %c ",str[i+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is deprecated and dangerous

Comment: `scanf("%i,&pstn")` -> `scanf("%i", ,&pstn)`

Comment: Please [edit] and describe in plain english what the `firstLetter` function is supposed to do and show some examples of expected outcome.

Comment: See @Jabberwocky's comment. Also, your while loop has the risk of running backwards past the beginning of the string.

Comment: Regarding: `str[5]` Your understanding of indexes contains a misconception.   in C, indexes start with 0 (not 1).  So, `str[5]` will select the 6th letter of `str[]`.

Comment: Regarding: `gets(str);`   The function `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language back in 2009.   Strongly suggest using `fgets()`  (which has a different parameter list from `gets()` )

Comment: the function: `firstLetter()` makes the (not necessarily valid) assumption that the sentence will contain multiple words.   Strongly suggest learning about [strtok()](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=syntax+for+strtok+in+c)` and using that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters in this line

```
scanf("%i,&pstn");
```

you have a typo. At least you need to rewrite it like

```
scanf("%i",&pstn);
```

Also within the function `firstLetter` there is also a typo in the if statement

```
if(str[i]=' ')
```

where you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard.

Instead use the function `fgets`

```
fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
```

The variable `pstn` should have the unsigned integer type `size_t`. Otherwise the user can enter a negative number.

Also you need to check that the entered position is not greater than the length of the string.

For example

```
size_t pstn = 0;
scanf("%zu", &pstn);

if ( pstn < strlen( str ) ) firstLetter(pstn, str);
```

The function parameter should have the qualifier const because the passed string is not changed within the function

Also the function has a bug because in this while loop

```
    while(str[i]!=' ')
    {
        i--;
    }
```

there is no check whether `i` is less than `0`.

Also the return type `int` of the function is useless.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void firstLetter( const char *str, size_t i )
{
    if ( str[i] == ' ' )
    {
        printf("No letters at this position");
    }
    else
    {
        while( i != 0 && str[i-1] != ' ' )
        {
            i--;
        }

        printf("First letter: %c\n", str[i] );
    }
}
```

So in main the function is called like

```
size_t pstn = 0;
scanf("%zu", &pstn);

if ( pstn < strlen( str ) ) firstLetter( str, pstn );
```

Or you can make the check that the specified position in the string is less than the length of the string within the function as for example

```
void firstLetter( const char *str, size_t i )
{
    if ( !( i < strlen( str ) ) || str[i] == ' ' )
    {
        printf("No letters at this position");
    }
    else
    {
        while( i != 0 && str[i-1] != ' ' )
        {
            i--;
        }

        printf("First letter: %c\n", str[i] );
    }
}
```

In this case the function is called like

```
size_t pstn = 0;
scanf("%zu", &pstn);

firstLetter( str, pstn );
```

Instead of the comparison with the space character `' '` you could compare with the space character `' '` and the tab character `'\t'` using the standard C function `isblank` declared in the header `<ctype.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void firstLetter( const char *str, size_t i )
{
    if ( !( i < strlen( str ) ) || isblank( ( unsigned char )str[i] ) )
    {
        printf("No letters at this position");
    }
    else
    {
        while( i != 0 && !isblank( ( unsigned char )str[i-1] ) )
        {
            i--;
        }

        printf("First letter: %c\n", str[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detalied review! I used int type and  return 0; because I read void is not in the C++ standard. I supposed it was the same for C.

Comment: @OlegPikhoff The type void  was introduced by Stroustrup exactly in the C++ and then was used in C.:)

Comment: sorry not C++ standard, but ANSI standard.  Why do we use int main(){reutrn 0;} then? can we just use void main()?

Comment: @OlegPikhoff The program returns a code to the operating system that runs the program. Nevertheless you may just write int main() {}.